# knockout ignore directive

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to get knockout to ignore the bindings even though apply bindings has been called on the page?

for example

```
<!-- ko with: ignore-->
<span title="City" data-bind="text: city"></span>
etc..
<!-- /ko -->
```

I'm getting errors in the page and it would be nice to wrap areas up until the model is ready.
I wouldn't do it this way normally but I have a lot of views with the data-bind directives in place.

```
return (new Function("sc", functionBody))(scopes);
uncaught exception: [Exception... "'Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: city is not defined;
knocko...ebug.js (line 195)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me your problem caused by application's architecture. I could propose workarounds for problem

1. `with: undefined` will not parse bindings. However elements will disappear from DOM and will never appear them since you have no way to re-evaluate `with` binding
2. Add IsViewModelReady observable to global context (window) and use `if: IsViewModelReady` binding. Set `window.IsViewModelReady(true)` when you are ready to bind. Checkout example: http://jsfiddle.net/romanych/6Wwux/

However my suggestion is to call `ko.applyBindings()` when all data needed for first render is ready. Also I want to notice that `ko.applyBindings` takes second argument `container` which defines DOM node to start scanning for `data-bind` attributes. You could apply binding to each part of page when you are ready. Check this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/romanych/4AjBA/

Comment: thanks, I think I'll use the if binding. thanks - helped a lot.

Comment: see also [Skip Binding](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html)